# Creating a function that returns a PromiEvent using web3-core-promievent

Tags: javascript, events, web3js

I've tried to run the following snippet, but to no avail.

I found the snippet [here](https://github.com/dedis/student_18_ethcalypso/tree/master/calypso/ethac/node_modules/web3-core-promievent).

```
var Web3PromiEvent = require('web3-core-promievent');

var myFunc = function(){
    var promiEvent = Web3PromiEvent();

    setTimeout(function() {
        promiEvent.eventEmitter.emit('done', 'Hello!');
        promiEvent.resolve('Hello!');
    }, 10);

     return promiEvent.eventEmitter;
};


// and run it
myFunc()
.then(console.log)
.on('done', console.log);
```

I always get this kind of error: TypeError: myFunc(...).then(...).on is not a function

It is critical for me to be able to have a way to emit events from my function, which signal that things happened during the function execution. I would prefer to use async/await syntax, if it is possible with it.

I would really like to avoid sending callback arguments to a function, but to be able to handle events as I see fit in different parts of code.

Comment: Couldn't you just do console.log(myFunc())?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misread the documentation, you can chain the `.on` method to the `Web3PromiEvent` object but not to the `Promise` object returned by the `.then`

so either you chain `.on` or you chain `.then`

```
myFunc()
.then(console.log);
```

or

```
myFunc()
.on('done', console.log);
```

As you see in the image below the `Promise` returned by the `.then` doesn't have the .on method attached whether the `Promise` returned by the `Web3PromiEvent` does.

[image]

this is the original example int the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-core-promievent)

```
// in node.js
var Web3PromiEvent = require('web3-core-promievent');

var myFunc = function(){
    var promiEvent = Web3PromiEvent();

    setTimeout(function() {
        promiEvent.eventEmitter.emit('done', 'Hello!');
        promiEvent.resolve('Hello!');
    }, 10);

    return promiEvent.eventEmitter;
};


// and run it
myFunc()
.then(console.log); //see the semicolon
.on('done', console.log); //see the semicolon
```